# Android Virtual Device armeabi-v7a but nothing for armv7?

Tags: eclipse, arm, android-virtual-device, armv7

all:

A naive question.

HP Touchpad comes with a **QUALCOMM Snapdragon APQ8060** processor, which is of **ARMv7** CPU instruction set.

Current Android Virtual Device Manager comes with only 3 sets of CPU/ABI,

1. ARM(armeabi-v7a)
2. MIPS(mips)
3. Intel Atom(x86)

My questions are:

- Does armeabi-v7a covers armv7? Or, are both compatible?
- Can I just select armeabi-v7a for HP touchpad (armv7) emulation?
- Is there a way to add my user-specified CPU/ABI?

Thank you...

Best Regards
Pei

Comment: *armeabi-v7a* is the same as per UnixSmurf.  Also, according to [Snapdragon product brief](http://www.qualcomm.com/media/documents/files/snapdragon-msm8x60-apq8060-product-brief.pdf), it is a Cortex-A9 equivalent. Just *google* it.

Answer (score 0):

The ARMv7 architecture comes in 3 flavours:

- Application (first implementation, Cortex-A8)
- Real-time (first implementation, Cortex-R4)
- Microcontroller (first implementation, Cortex-M3)

Only the "A" profile provides a Memory Management Unit - so if your device is ARMv7 and it supports running off-the-shelf Android, it is an ARMv7-A device.

armeabi describes the ABI used, not the hardware.